# how to scale background-image proportionally with container in CSS with

Tags: html, css, containers

for a small codeing project in codehs.com I have separate containers some labeled image some with actual images however i cannot figure out how to scale proportionally with size of webpage

here is the code for my project:
index.html

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial;
  padding: 10px;
  background-image: url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSYY0m5M4elle5s14mIhUSPJQJNXWE626vaxJfyLMp-t5aQYsuS8fDBTApBr1bvM6Yu4L4:https://files.123freevectors.com/wp-content/original/110787-dark-color-blurred-background-vector.jpg&usqp=CAU);
  background-size: cover;
}


/* Header/Blog Title */

.header {
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  background: white;
}

.header h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
}


/* Style the top navigation bar */

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}


/* Style the topnav links */

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* Change color on hover */

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}


/* Create two unequal columns that floats next to each other */


/* Left column */

.leftcolumn {
  float: left;
  width: 75%;
}


/* Right column */

.rightcolumn {
  float: right;
  width: 25%;
  padding-left: 20px;
}


/* Fake image */

.fakeimg {
  background-color: #aaa;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
}

#first3dp {
  background-image: url("https://i.all3dp.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/21134921/Lead.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}


/* Add a card effect for articles */

.card {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}


/* Clear floats after the columns */

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


/* Footer */

.footer {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #ddd;
  margin-top: 20px;
}


/* Responsive layout - when the screen is less than 800px wide, make the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .leftcolumn,
  .rightcolumn {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
  }
}


/* Responsive layout - when the screen is less than 400px wide, make the navigation links stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .topnav a {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSzbKAzXZFQY6Sf3Jkfh_f8XPYJSMt1vHb5ZYCj4IjghC6Ue-cKiUAg78vx09asJCYmiw:https://www.fbla-pbl.org/media/2022/09/FBLA_HorizontalLogo_cropped-01.png&usqp=CAU">
  <h1>Alex's 3D Printing Journey</h1>
  <p></p>
</div>

<div class="topnav">
  <a href="#">Link</a>
  <a href="#">Link</a>
  <a href="#">Link</a>
  <a href="#" style="float:right">Contact me</a>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="leftcolumn">
    <div class="card">
      <h2>Where it started!</h2>
      <h5>sometime, 2020</h5>
      <div class="fakeimg" id="first3dp" style="height:200px;"> </div>
      <p>Some text..</p>
      <p></p>
    </div>

    <!--<img src="https://i.all3dp.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/21134921/Lead.jpg"> -->

    <div class="card">
      <h2>TITLE HEADING</h2>
      <h5>Title description, Sep 2, 2022</h5>
      <div class="fakeimg" style="height:200px;">Image</div>
      <p>Some text..</p>
      <p></p>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="rightcolumn">
    <div class="card">
      <h2>About Us</h2>
      <div class="fakeimg" style="height:100px;">Image</div>
      <p>text...</p>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
      <h3>Popular Post</h3>
      <div class="fakeimg">
        <p>Image</p>
      </div>
      <div class="fakeimg">
        <p>Image</p>
      </div>
      <div class="fakeimg">
        <p>Image</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card">
      <h3>Follow Us</h3>
      <p>Some text.. can use embed with social media links</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="footer">
  <h2>Footer</h2>
  <h2>Footer to include credits to website creators and copyright information</h2>
</div>
```

use of background-size: cover;
in the id #first3dp on style.css however it did fit it to the container it did not scale proportionally with the container rather resizing the image kicking it off screen

Comment: What is the expected result ?  `contain` would rescale the image without loosing ratio but won't fill the whole container, `100% 100%`  will distort it ... options can be find here  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Comment: Use a `background-size: 100% 100%;`

Comment: thank you I was unaware of the contain property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your need to add the background-position property is you want a specific position when using background images in CSS.. add this code I also fixed your header which was overflowing.

```
.header > *{
  width: 100%;
}
#first3dp {
      background-image: url("https://i.all3dp.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/21134921/Lead.jpg");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
    }
```

Comment: if 100% width for your header image is too much than what you like simply adjust the percentage number I recommend around 50% or 70%

Comment: thank you for going above and beyond on helping me with my project

Answer (score 0):

On the `header` `img` use `max-width: 100%;`